# Run multiple bat files which has "pause" in it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following 2 bat files:

```
1.bat
------
//a line which does something
pause

2.bat
------
//a line which does the other something
pause
```

Now, how do I run these bat files within a new bat file, by ignoring the pause(s)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple: Remove the `PAUSE`!

But I assume, one of your restrictions of the problem could be, that you can't remove the `pause`.

Then you could use redirection to the called batch file.

Something like

```
call 1.bat < nul
call 2.bat < nul
```

Comment: I was about to post something like that, only I was going to suggest `ECHO(| 1.bat` and I actually like your suggestion *much* better. Anyway, it may be worth mentioning that the trick will work if the batch files do not read `stdin` (otherwise than through their `pause` commands).